# newton raphson in C

Tags: c, algorithm, numerical-methods

I have implemented the newton raphson algorithm for finding roots in C. I want to print out the most accurate approximation of the root as possible without going into nan land. My strategy for this is `while (!(isnan(x0)) { dostuff(); }` But this continues to print out the result multiple times. Ideally I would like to setup a range so that the difference between each computed x intercept approximation would stop when the previous - current is less than some range .000001 in my case. I have a possible implementation below. When I input 2.999 It takes only one step, but when I input 3.0 it takes 20 steps, this seems incorrect to me.

(When I input 3.0)

```
λ newton_raphson 3
2.500000
2.250000
2.125000
2.062500
2.031250
2.015625
2.007812
2.003906
2.001953
2.000977
2.000488
2.000244
2.000122
2.000061
2.000031
2.000015
2.000008
2.000004
2.000002
2.000001
Took 20 operation(s) to approximate a proper root of 2.000002
within a range of 0.000001
```

(When I input 2.999)

```
λ newton_raphson 2.999
Took 1 operation(s) to approximate a proper root of 2.000000
within a range of 0.000001
```

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#define RANGE 0.000001


double absolute(double number)
{
    if (number < 0) return -number;
    else return number;
}

 double newton_raphson(double (*func)(double), double (*derivative)(double), double x0){
    int count;
    double temp;
    count = 0;
    while (!isnan(x0)) {
            temp = x0;
            x0 = (x0 - (func(x0)/derivative(x0)));
            if (!isnan(x0))
                printf("%f\n", x0);
            count++;
            if (absolute(temp - x0) < RANGE && count > 1)
                break;
    }
    printf("Took %d operation(s) to approximate a proper root of %6f\nwithin a range of 0.000001\n", count, temp);
    return x0;
 }


/* (x-2)^2 */
 double func(double x){ return pow(x-2.0, 2.0); }
/* 2x-4 */
 double derivative(double x){ return 2.0*x - 4.0; }

 int main(int argc, char ** argv)
 {
   double x0 = atof(argv[1]);
   double (*funcPtr)(double) = &func; /* this is a user defined function */
   double (*derivativePtr)(double) = &derivative; /* this is the derivative of that function */

   double result = newton_raphson(funcPtr, derivativePtr, x0);
   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: I know this is probably not production code, but please use check arguments before you use them, e.g. `if (NULL == argv[1]) { ... print help ... ; return 0; }`. Otherwise your programs segfault without arguments.

Comment: You are using double precision in the calculations but not showing all the digits in your printf(). change your format string to "%.15f\n" to get more digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call `trunc(x0)` which turns `2.999` into `2.0`. Naturally, when you start at the right answer, no iteration is needed! In other words, although you intended to use `2.999` as your starting value, you actually used `2.0`.

Simply remove the call to `trunc()`.

Comment: You're welcome. Took me a surprising amount of time to spot it myself!

Comment: I think that sums it up (no pun intended), Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Worth pointing out: taking 20 steps to converge is *also* anomalous; because you are converging to a multiple root, the convergence is only linear instead of the typical quadratic convergence that Newton-Raphson gives in the general case.  You can see this in the fact that your error is halved with each iteration (with the usual quadratic convergence, you would get twice as many correct digits on each iteration, and converge much, much faster).